# java how to sort to new array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying sorting an array a but I want the sorted array to save in an array b and that the array a keeps unsorted? How can I achieve that?

I've tried the Arrays.sort(a) method and I've got this little piece of code, but when I try to acess a, it is allways sorted :\

```
public static int[] sortArray(int a[]){
    int b[] = a;
    int len=b.length;
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<len-1;j++){
            if(b[j]>b[j+1]){
                temp=b[j+1];
                b[j+1]=b[j];
                b[j]=temp;
            }
        } 
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] a = new int[]{5,2,4,8,4,5};
int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
Arrays.sort(b);
```

CONTENTS:
a: [5,2,4,8,4,5]
b: [2,4,4,5,5,8]

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a *deep-copy* of `a`, and then sort and return that copy:

```
public static int[] sortArray(int a[]){
    int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
    Arrays.sort(b);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not creating a new array `b`, you're just making `b` another reference to `a`.  I would create `b` using:

```
int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
```

then use `Arrays.sort(b)` to produce a sorted `b` array without affecting `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring int b[] = new int[a.length] then copy each elements like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
b[i] = a[i];
}
```

Full code:

```
public static int[] sortArray(int a[]){
    int b[] = = new int[a.length]
for(int j = 0; j < a.length; ++j) {
    b[j] = a[j];
    }
    int len=b.length;
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<len-1;j++){
            if(b[j]>b[j+1]){
                temp=b[j+1];
                b[j+1]=b[j];
                b[j]=temp;
            }
        } 
    }
    return b;
}
```